# Get object by name as string without eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

The code below does what I want, but I would like to avoid `eval`. Is there a function in Javascript that looks up an object by its name as defined by in a string?

```
myobject = {"foo" : "bar"}
myname = "myobject";
eval(myname);
```

Some context: I am using this for an application in which a large number of nodes in the dom has a html5 `data-object` attribute, which is used in the handler function to connect back to the model.

Edit: myobject is neither global nor local, it is defined in one of the parent frames of the handler.

Comment: Is `myobject` a local or global variable?

Comment: You keep the models data in variables? I don't have much experience with MVC, but usually you want to keep a reference to your models in your views or collections...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If variables are global then:

```
myobject = {"foo" : "bar"};
myname = "myobject";
window[myname].foo
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Xhm/1/)**

For local:

```
(function(){
    myobject = {"foo" : "bar"};
    myname = "myobject";
    alert( this[myname].foo );
})();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Xhm/3/)**

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I know Sir, just for OP's case. Thanks

Comment: Your second example is a kind of misleading. It's basically the same as the first one - you define `myobject` without `var` (means: globally) and then access it by `window[myname]` (because `this === window`, in your case).
As soon as your context (your `this`) changes, your example won't work anymore. Long story short: That's not a way to access local variables by name.

Answer (score 14):

**Local Variable Solution:**

You could make all objects that you want to access with a string properties of another object. For example:

```
var objectHolder = {
    myobject: {"foo" : "bar"},
    myobject2: {"foo" : "bar"},
    myobject3: {"foo" : "bar"}
};
```

And then access your desired object like this:

```
var desiredObject = objectHolder["myobject"];
```

---

**Global Variable Solution:**

You can access global variables using a string like this:

```
window["myobject"];
```

Comment: You probably forgot to replace the equal signs with colons in the first part of your post.

Answer (score 7):

This question is pretty old, but since it's the top result on Google for the query "javascript get object from string", I thought I'd share a technique for longer object paths using dot notation.

Given the following:

```
var foo = { 'bar': { 'alpha': 'beta' } };
```

We can get the value of 'alpha' from a string like this:

```
var objPath = "bar.alpha";

var alphaVal = objPath.split('.')
  .reduce(function (object, property) {

    return object[property];
  }, foo);

// alphaVal === "beta"
```

If it's global:

```
window.foo = { 'bar': { 'alpha': 'beta' } };
```

Just pass `window` as the `initialValue` for `reduce`:

```
var objPath = "foo.bar.alpha";

var alphaVal = objPath.split('.')
  .reduce(function (object, property) {

    return object[property];
  }, window);

// alphaVal === "beta"
```

Basically we can use `reduce` to traverse object members by passing in the initial object as the `initialValue`.

[MDN article for Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3):

since window is a global namespace, you could simply use

```
window[myname]
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a fair bit of dotted notation variable structures. Needed a way to traverse them without erroring on undefined, and return value or undefined as the answer. Hope this helps.

```
function getValueOrUndefined(id) {
    let parent = window;
    if (id.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        let current = null;
        let child = undefined;
        let names = id.split(".");
        for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            current = names[i];
            child = parent[current];
            if (child === undefined)
                return child;
            else
                parent = child; 
        }
        return child; 
    }
    return parent[id];
}
```